# Why does adding opacity break 3D CSS animations?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, opacity, css-transforms

This is my base animation. Everything here works fine unless *1* line of code is added to the `div, div::before, div::after { }` selector.

```css
*, * ::before, * ::after {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
html { overflow: hidden; background-color: #eee; }
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  color: #999;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
main, div, div::before, div::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body {
  perspective: 20rem;
}
div, div::before, div::after {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center center -5rem;
  width: 10rem; height: 10rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb( 221, 221, 221, 0.75 );
}
```

```html
<style>
  div::before {
    transform: rotateX( 90deg ); content: 'top';
  }
  div::after {
    transform: rotateX( -90deg ); content: 'bottom';
  }
  div > div {
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform-origin: center center center;
  }
  div > div::before {
    transform: rotateY( 90deg ); content: 'right';
  }
  div > div::after {
    transform: rotateY( -90deg ); content: 'left';
  }
  .rotate_y { animation-name: rotate_y; }
  @keyframes rotate_y {
    0% { transform: rotateY( 0deg ); } 100% { transform: rotateY( 360deg ); }
  }
  .rotate_x { animation-name: rotate_x; animation-duration: 200s; }
  @keyframes rotate_x {
    0% { transform: rotateX( 0deg ) scale( 1 ); } 
    100% { transform: rotateX( 360deg ) scale( -6 ); }
  }
</style>

<main class='rotate_x'>
  <div class='rotate_y'>
    front <div>back</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

When the following code is added all of the selected elements proceed to **disappear** *except* for the non-pseudo elements.

```
div, div::before, div::after {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Below is a demonstration with a *comment* in the CSS following the new line of code added:

```css
*, * ::before, * ::after {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
html { overflow: hidden; background-color: #eee; }
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  color: #999;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
main, div, div::before, div::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body {
  perspective: 20rem;
}
div, div::before, div::after {
  position: absolute; transform-origin: center center -5rem;
  width: 10rem; height: 10rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb( 221, 221, 221, 0.75 );
  opacity: 0.9; /* this is the only line that has changed from the first snippet */  
}
```

```html
<style>
  div::before {
    transform: rotateX( 90deg ); content: 'top';
  }
  div::after {
    transform: rotateX( -90deg ); content: 'bottom';
  }
  div > div {
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform-origin: center center center;
  }
  div > div::before {
    transform: rotateY( 90deg ); content: 'right';
  }
  div > div::after {
    transform: rotateY( -90deg ); content: 'left';
  }
  .rotate_y { animation-name: rotate_y; }
  @keyframes rotate_y {
    0% { transform: rotateY( 0deg ); } 100% { transform: rotateY( 360deg ); }
  }
  .rotate_x { animation-name: rotate_x; animation-duration: 200s; }
  @keyframes rotate_x {
    0% { transform: rotateX( 0deg ) scale( 1 ); } 
    100% { transform: rotateX( 360deg ) scale( -6 ); }
  }
</style>

<main class='rotate_x'>
  <div class='rotate_y'>
    front <div>back</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

All of the pseudo elements are gone. Also the '*front*' and '*back*' `div`s have been flattened. The whole animation breaks.

**Why does this behavior occur and is it possible to implement the `opacity` property on a 3D CSS animation. If so; how?**

Comment: Just some observations: putting opacity: 0.9 on the pseudo elements does not seem to break anything. Putting it on all divs, or only on the class rotate_y div, does. Putting it on main does not totally break things but it seems to slightly distort, as if it's not managing perspective in one direction.

Comment: I also notice on IOS it doesn’t actually break at all due to opacity. The opacity part behaves expectedly but **both** snippets are broken on IOS in a different way lol. The alignment of the faces are off. But yes; opacity works as expected on IOS.

Comment: Yes I’ve just tried it in IOS, iPad, and both snippets are off but similarly.

Comment: @devsandbox this is happening because `opacity` affects the rendering of 3D like it does stacking context. Check out this link to read more: https://css-tricks.com/things-watch-working-css-3d/#3-opacity